# Redis healthcheck from application

Tags: redis, health-check

What is the proper way to healthcheck Redis from application?
Is there any analogue of sql: `SELECT 1;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [PING](https://redis.io/commands/PING) command. Quoting from the redis documentation

> This command is often used to test if a connection is still alive, or to measure latency.